# Feedback, LiveChat or Call me Buttons - How to - Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am looking for the best technology to provide customer ways to add our functionality through buttons on their websites.

I know this can be done adding button to a body and attaching a click listener but I am stumped at a point where I need to resize my iframe (UI after they click a button) and it cannot be done from internal iframe.

I wanted to check how getsatisfaction, invox, zendesk and other companies offer this functionality.

Is there a quick tip for this? I am just looking for modus operandi and not actual code.

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://theezpzway.com/2009/5/1/how-to-build-a-personal-mashup-page-with-jquery) or google it with phrase "jquery mashup example" could only help you.

The solution you want to implement is not possible because of cross domain security (policy) browser will not allow you to communicate with parent window. If you are in same domain as parent window, then you could only be able to something like this in child (IFRAME)

```
$(function(){
        window.parent.document.getElementById("thisAsIframe").width = 800;
        window.parent.document.getElementById("thisAsIframe").height = 800;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Milan but this is not what I am looking for. I understand JSON and other concepts but my question is how to implement a button like interface exposing it as an iframe and adjusting its height dynamically avoiding third party domain restrictions.

Comment: There reason why your solution can't do is above your comment, I have updated my previous post.